# How to change URL by replacing ID's with Product names using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Every product in my ecom site is opened using the product name passed in the URL, which will make the URL look like this:

```
www.mysite.com/Products/Product-Name
```

But it's trying to find the page named **"Product-Name"** inside the folder **"Products"**.
In reality, I don't have any of those folders.

Instead, how can I write the condition in htaccess to not look for the page, so that I can fetch the last part of the URL (i.e., Product name and get the data from DB) and the second last part of the URL to identify for what the user is searching for.

**So far my.htaccess file goes as:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Thanks in advance.

(In a glance):

My URL: **[www.mysite.com/Products/Product-Name](http://www.mysite.com/Products/Product-Name)**
But It should open the page: **[www.mysite.com/products.php](http://www.mysite.com/products.php)**

(By keeping the URL the same as 'www.mysite.com/Products/Product-Name' so that I can use JS to fetch parts of URL to work with)

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention more clearly like: **from** which sample URL **to** which sample url you want to redirect/rewrite? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @RavinderSingh13 Thanks for asking, i have updated the question, please check more time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have your .htaccess in following manner. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. Apart from adding new rules to your already tried .htaccess file I have changed the sequence of few rules eg: NON http --> http rule should be at the top of your .htaccess rules file.

Also make sure that your .htaccess rules file and products.php are residing in same folder/directory only.

```
RewriteEngine ON

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

##New rules added for internal rewrite from here.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^Products/Product-Name/?$ products.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/cpanel-dcv/[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/(?:\ Ballot169)?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code, the middle "New rules" (3 lines) are giving me the error as `Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` and page doesn't load at all.

Comment: @Harry, I am Sorry there was a typo, please copy/paste my new rules and try it once. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

Comment: @Harry, Did it work out for you? cheers